# java restful web service explanation

Tags: java, json, web-services, http, rest

I am completely new to Java web services. I have written following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL("www.somehost.com/somedata");
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

      if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed: HTTP error code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
      }
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          conn.getInputStream()
      ));
      String output;
      while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
      }
      conn.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

My task is to create a web service that returns data in `JSON` format from "some URL". I want to create a `RESTful` web service but I do not realize how to modify the code to serve it as a web service. Can anybody explain/show what else I should do?

Comment: The code you have here is not a webservice but a client for a webservice. To create a restful webservice with Java EE 7 have a look at the following short youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zESNqWcY0pY

Comment: video is currencty unavailably

Comment: Can you explain/show what else I should do?

Comment: for me only the flash version of the video works, but there doesn't seem to be a HTML5 version. So make sure you have flashplayer installed

Comment: Btw.: You should call conn.connect() before conn.getResponseCode()

Comment: for creating a restful webservice with Java EE 6 have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

Comment: If this is a client for a web service, then what should I write into web service?

Comment: well with the client you are consuming a webservice... the webservice itself provides the data for the client... The client would say: "webservice give me the resource which is located at www.somehost.com/somedata in the json format"... the webservice answers with whatever data you want it to return in json format

Comment: So, all this code I should put into web service and in click just call this webservice?

Comment: no, as I said you'll need that code to call the webservice with java... IMHO you don't really need the client code because you can use any browser as a client to get the JSON from the webservice. This article should answer all your questions: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: can you provide me with examples about webservices fetching data from some URL?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Jersey resource example:

```
@Path("rest/heartbeat")
public class HeartbeatResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response heartbeatGet() {
        return Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .entity(new Messages("I am alive!")).build();
    }
}
```

Do some research and choose a solid REST framework, if it happens to be Jersey then you can find needed learning documents at: https://jersey.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Apace Wink to develop RESTful services.. It gives you capability to tune the API as per you need .
http://wink.apache.org/